# If the empirical cdf uniformly converges to the cdf, does the empirical expected value also uniformly converge?

Tags: probability, expected-value, asymptotics

If a random variable $X$ has an unknown cdf $F(X)$ and empirical cdf $\hat F(X)$, and $\hat F(X)$ uniformly converges to $F(X)$ via the Glivenko-Cantelli theorem, does $E[X]$ w.r.t. the empirical pdf $\hat f(X)$ also uniformly converge to $E[X]$ w.r.t. $f(X)$?

Comment: Hint: the expectation can be expressed in terms of integrals of $F$ and $1-F$.

Comment: Thank you @whuber, I can combine that fact with proposition 2 from https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m43s12/public_html/notes/class8.pdf

Comment: @whuber in my case the random variable X happens to be non-negative, which allows use of the integral of $1-F$. Would this statement not hold true if that weren't the case?

Comment: The expectation exists if and only if both the positive and negative parts are finite.  The positive part is found by integrating $1-F$ from $0$ to $\infty$ while the negative part is found by integrating $F$ from $0$ to $-\infty$.